# transaction in function of postgtresql

Tags: postgresql

From the research I have done so far. what I have found is that in postgrsql functions can not be transactionized from within. They had to be called by a piece of code which can be transactionized. We have requirement to introduce transaction on db level. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you refer to "research", provide *links* to things that support what you're saying. Also, *always include your exact PostgreSQL version* in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I think you want autonomous subtransactions. These are not supported by PostgreSQL at this time (9.3 or older). The standard workaround is to use DBLink to have PostgreSQL make a new connection to its self. It's not super-efficient, but it works.

See [this blog](http://raghavt.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/autonomous-transaction-in-postgresql-91.html) provides one useful example of using the [dblink extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) to achieve autonomous subtransactions.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I tried that. I encounter the problem with this approach too. when I use dblink and one of the statements fails. it doesnt commit. which is the good thing. but it also never runs the dblink_disconnect command. so next time when I come after correcting my code. I have to drop the extension dblink. and then redo it altogether. I ll explore this further though.

Comment: work around might be to call dblink in another function. and call this function after every function call, which involves transaction code. Right?

Comment: @user433023 Just disconnect and reconnect. When the `psql` session ends, so will any remaining dblink sessions.